# React Redux Problem With Google Auth Sign In

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-authentication

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth to my application. When I click the "Sign in With Google" button that I made, Google login will pop UP. but after that I can't see any changes in my Redux devtools and It won't Sign In

My code works when I enter the following code in the browser's console like `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()` then my button will change from Signed in with google to SignOut after that, I got Signed In. And I see changes to my redux dev tools that It works. but for some reason It won't worked when Click the button of my App.

**GoogLeAuth.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signIn, signOut } from "./actions/index";

class GoogleAuth extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.client
        .init({
          clientId:
            "ID",
          scope: "email"
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
          this.onAuthChange(this.auth.isSignedIn.get());
          this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(this.onAuthChange);
        });
    });
  }

  onAuthChange = isSignedIn => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      this.props.signIn(this.auth.currentUser.get().getId());
    } else {
      this.props.signOut();
    }
  };
  onSignInClick = () => {
    this.auth.signIn();
  };

  onSignOutClick = () => {
    this.auth.signOut();
  };

  authButton = () => {
    if (this.props.isSignedIn === null) {
      return null;
    } else if (this.props.isSignedIn) {
      return <button onClick={this.onSignOutClick}>Sign Out</button>;
    } else {
      return <button onClick={this.onSignInClick}>Sign In with Google</button>;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.authButton()}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { signIn, signOut }
)(GoogleAuth);
```

Comment: where is `this.auth` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to call the `signIn` action in `onSignInClick`:

```
onSignInClick = () => {
    this.auth.signIn();
    this.props.signIn();
};
```

Same with `signOut` in `onSignOutClick`.